# Java JTable AttributiveCellTableModel add row

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, addition

i'am using the AttributiveCellTableModel for merging cells in my table.

http://www-st.inf.tu-dresden.de/SalesPoint/v3.1/faq/SwingExamples/html/jtable4.html

But the problem is, that

```
model.addRow(new Object[]{the values});
```

doesn't work.
With the DefaultTableModel it works but not with this AttributiveCellTableModel.

does anyone know how to fix that problem?

thanks in advance

mirisbowring

Answer (score 1):

Well the model overrides the `addRow( Vector )` method, but not the `addRow( Object[] )` method of the `DefaultTableModel`.

So this means you need to modfify the code and implement the `addRow( Object[] )` method yourself.

The way to do this is to create a `Vector` and then just copy the items in the `Array` to the `Vector`. Then you can invoke the `addRow( Vector )` method of the model.

Something like:

```
@Override
public void addRow(Object[] arrayRow)
{
    Vector vectorRow = new Vector(arrayRow.length);

    for (...)
        // copy each item in the array to the vector

    addRow( vectorRow );
}
```

Comment: Oh ok... I did that, but that doesn't change anything :/ I keep getting an Error at this: |int numRows    = oldSpan.length;| in DefaultCellAttribut.java (line 175)

Comment: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Comment: @mirisbowring, Well, then you need to debug the code. That is not a standard JDK class so you are responsible for fixing any bugs.

Comment: mhm i tried many things, but nothing worked...  I'm getting the Error in the default addRow() Method (though i createt an object Method)...

Answer (score 0):

For dynamic adding you should fix several bugs:

```
  public void setDataVector(Vector newData, Vector columnNames) {
    if (newData == null)
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("setDataVector() - Null parameter");
    dataVector = new Vector(0);

    dataVector = newData;

    // 2021/02/03 Bug fix.
    //setColumnIdentifiers(columnNames);
    columnIdentifiers = columnNames;

    cellAtt = new DefaultCellAttribute(dataVector.size(),
                                       columnIdentifiers.size());

    newRowsAdded(new TableModelEvent(this, 0, getRowCount()-1,
         TableModelEvent.ALL_COLUMNS, TableModelEvent.INSERT));
  }

  @Override
  public void addRow(Vector rowData) {
    insertRow(getRowCount(), rowData);
  }

  @Override
  public void insertRow(int row) {
    int[][][] oldSpan = span;
    int numRows    = oldSpan.length;
    int numColumns = oldSpan[0].length;
    span = new int[numRows + 1][numColumns][2];

    //2021/02/03 Bug fix.
    //if (0 < row) {
    //  System.arraycopy(oldSpan,0,span,0,row-1);
    //}
    //System.arraycopy(oldSpan,0,span,row,numRows - row);
    if (row == numRows) {
      System.arraycopy(oldSpan,0,span,0,numRows);
    } else {
      System.arraycopy(oldSpan, 0, span, 0, row);
      System.arraycopy(oldSpan, row, span, row + 1, numRows - row);
    }

    for (int i=0;i<numColumns;i++) {
      span[row][i][CellSpan.COLUMN] = 1;
      span[row][i][CellSpan.ROW]    = 1;
    }

    //2021/02/03 Bug fix.
    rowSize++;
  }
```